# CSS font-family !important declaration ignored in iOS/Safari

Tags: html, ios, css, fonts, safari

I'm working on this [site](http://www.teazleconsulting.co.uk/) and I have this CSS

```
.n2-font-d7df9860b9d2e958d0b5b8dadd6b6bd5-paragraph{
    font-family:'HelveticaNeue', 'Helvetica Neue', serif !important;
}
```

This targets the text on the front page image (please don't ask about the selector - its generated by a plugin!). I need to use the Helvetica Neue font and I believe its supported in iOS ([iosfonts.com](http://iosfonts.com/)). It looks fine on desktop browsers, but the font-family is ignored on iOS (in Safari) and renders as a flat sans-serif font.

I've tried listing various alternatives but with no success. I am using iOS 9.2.1 which is the latest.

Can anyone say why I'm having this issue? And how to make it apply the correct font? I'm about ready to smash stuff... Thanks for any advice.

Comment: Just do a test like color:red!important; to make sure the selector is be applied.

Comment: I hadn't thought of that, but yes, that was applied OK on both desktop and Safari/iOS. So, is this the font selector not being recognised do you think?

Comment: If that color applies then the selector should be fine, another way would using the Safari remote debug and find out what's really going on.

Comment: It just doesn't actually work though, hence the mystery and my question! Safari remote debug seems like quite a chore for this, especially as I'm in Windows, but I will look into it further. Thanks for your input :)

Comment: tried a different font, which you know exists? or even a `font-family: monospace!important`? Because if the class is getting applied, good bet you *don't* actually have Helvetica Neue available (at least not with those names)